# Grow/shrink selection?

Tags: edit-mode

Using updated version 2.83.1. Grow/shrink selection hotkey is different to Ctrl + +/-. Need step by step to change or find the assigned hotkey Thanks.

Comment: **Ctrl  Numpad +** works fine for me.

Comment: I can confirm - Ctrl + Numpad +/- works as usual (works in 2.90 as well)

Comment: Thanks I had to use the onscreen numpad as my laptop does not have a numpad.